# How to extract feature names used by the first tree in GradientBoostingRegressor in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I want to print the names of the features from my **first estimator** of `GradientBoostingRegressor`, but getting the below error.
**Scikit_learn** version = `1.2.2`

```
model.estimators_[0]._final_estimator.feature_names_in_

output:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[115], line 1
----> 1 model.estimators_[0]._final_estimator.feature_names_in_

AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingRegressor' object has no attribute 'feature_names_in_'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write that you want to specifically get the feature names of the **first** estimator of the ensemble. Unfortunately, the **feature names of the individual trees are not stored**. That's why it gives you the error

```
AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingRegressor' object has no attribute 'feature_names_in_'
```

However, since they are trained on the same set of features as the entire model, the feature names from the main `GradientBoostingRegressor` are available to each of its decision trees. So you can extract the feature names of the ensemble (and thus **available to the first tree**) like this:

```
model.feature_names_in_
```

If you are interested by the feature names **used by the first tree**, you can do it like this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset
data = fetch_california_housing()
X, y = data.data, data.target
feature_names = data.feature_names

# Create and fit the GradientBoostingRegressor
model = GradientBoostingRegressor(max_features=0.5, random_state=0)
model.fit(X, y)  # Directly fit on X, y without converting to DataFrame

# Access the first tree of the first estimator
first_tree = model.estimators_[0, 0]

# Get the feature indices used in the first tree and filter out non-features
used_feature_indices = set([i for i in first_tree.tree_.feature if i >= 0])

# Map indices to feature names
used_feature_names = [feature_names[i] for i in used_feature_indices]

print("All feature names:", feature_names)
print("Names of features used in the first tree:", used_feature_names)
print("Names of features not used in the first tree:", set(feature_names) - set(used_feature_names))
```